# driver of mysql?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

what will I put in this code, in the braces--> (MySQL}

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Driver={MySQL};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=student;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here [MySQL Connection Strings](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/ASP/mysql_connection_strings.php)

```
'declare the variable that will hold the connection string
Dim ConnectionString 
'define connection string, specify database driver and location of the database 
ConnectionString= "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost;" &_ 
"DATABASE=your_mysql_database; UID=your_username; PASSWORD=your_password; OPTION=3"
```